# A simple series of set-theoretic operations (unions and intersections)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I evaluate the expression $$ (A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n) \cap (B_1\cup \ldots \cup B_m) \cap (C_1 \cup \ldots \cup C_o) ?$$

I know that for $(A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n) \cap B_1$ we get $((A_1\cap B_1) \cup \ldots \cup (A_n\cap B_1))$, but don't knw how the generalize this to the above.

Comment: In what sense do you mean "evaluate" - and in what context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Step 1:** Replace $A=A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_n$, and similarly $B$ and $C$. We have $A\cap B\cap C$.
2. **Step 2:** Simplify. In this case this is simplified as it is.
3. **Step 3:** Put $A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_n$ back in, add parenthesis. We have $((A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_n)\cap B)\cap C$.
4. **Step 4:** Distribute. We have $(A_1\cap B\cup\ldots\cup A_n\cap B)\cap C$.
5. **Step 5:** Restore the $B_1\cup\ldots\cup B_m$. The indices are now long and tiresome.
6. **Step 6:** Distribute $A_i\cap(B_1\cup\ldots\cup B_m)$.
7. **Step 7:** Distribute the intersection with $C$. Arrive at the union small expressions of the form $(A_i\cap B_j\cap C)$.
8. **Step 8:** Place the union of $C_k$'s into the expression.
9. **Step 9:** Distribute.
10. **Step 10:** Have a beer and recall how much bookkeeping after indices is terrible!

We end up with the union of $A_i\cap B_j\cap C_k$ for $i\leq n, j\leq m, k\leq o$.

Comment: Nice Asaf. Honestly I haven't seen such this generalization and wonder who can manage it as it should be. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @AsafKaragila Would this also work, if we either had an arbitrary (not a finite) union of sets, or one or all of sets would consist of arbitrary intersections  - or both ?

Comment: @arila: Yes, it would. Although it would be slightly harder to write it cleanly when you have an arbitrary intersection of arbitrary unions.

Comment: Sometimes these questions are best thought through in terms of elements. You could think about what it means for $x$ to be an element of the set given by the intersection - $x$ has to be a member of all of the component unions.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, this is very true. I think that it's an excellent approach for the general case. I also think that everyone should at least one time keep track of indices, so they'll know how much it is preferred to be avoided! :-)